# XLRelease [Xebia Labs] cannot concatenate 'unicode' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: nexus, artifact, xlrelease

I'm trying to deploy the application using XLRelease/XLDeploy by calling Jenkins job.
I've made the work flow like:

-> Confirm approval 
-> Check if artifact exists in Nexus 
-> Jenkins Build/Upload to Nexus & Upload DAR to XLDeploy
attached the input details: 
[image]
[image]
[image]
Over here during this stage (ie. Check if artifact exists in Nexus ) I'm getting following error message:

**Exception during execution:
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'unicode' and 'NoneType' objects in  at line number 55**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution,
I missed to provide "password" details.
After i pop in the login details everything works like a charm.
Hope this will be helpful for someone in the future.

Thanks!